# DAX Function to get list camera_id appear the first time since it did not appear 21 days before

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have struggled with creating DAX function DAX Function to get list camera_id with [action]="Intrusion" appear the first time since it did not appear 21 days before by date
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10wbM.png)

Data.Sample: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/129ANZHYdsKSYVQuL5ZijEit0TdQ1erOMkxgLlnIG0Rc/edit#gid=0)

Outcome I want: list of camera_id by date

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query do the following steps

1. Filter the rows by Action = Intrusion
2. Group by Camera_id with following M code to populate Row Rank column

   `=Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Camera_id"}, {{"AllRowsGrouped",     each Table.AddIndexColumn( Table.Sort(_,{{"Date",  Order.Ascending}}), "Row Rank",1,1), type table [ID=nullable number, Date=nullable date, Camera_id=nullable number, Action=nullable text, Row Rank=nullable number]}})`
3. Expand the table in each row by selecting Date and Row Rank columns

In Data view do following steps

4. Write a calculated column with following dax code

`Column = DATEDIFF(LOOKUPVALUE(Sheet1[AllRowsGrouped.Date],Sheet1[Camera_id], Sheet1[Camera_id],Sheet1[AllRowsGrouped.Row Rank],Sheet1[AllRowsGrouped.Row Rank]-1),Sheet1[AllRowsGrouped.Date],DAY)`

5. Write a measure with
   `Measure = COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE(Sheet1, FILTER(Sheet1, Sheet1[Column] > 21)))`
6. Create a table with following dax code

`Table = SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(SUMMARIZE('Sheet1', 'Sheet1'[Camera_id], ">21", [Measure]), 'Sheet1'[Measure] >=1), "Camera_id", 'Sheet1'[Camera_id])`

[image]

Comment: Is there any ways to handle it just using DAX function in Data view, don't do anything in this table in power query?

Answer (score 0):

In Data view do the following steps

1. Filter the rows by Action = Intrusion using DAX:
   `Table = CALCULATETABLE(Sheet1, Sheet1[Action] = "Intrusion")`
2. Populate Row Rank column using calculated column using DAX

`Row Rank = RANKX(FILTER('Table','Table'[Camera_id]=EARLIER('Table'[Camera_id])), 'Table'[Date] )`

4. Write a calculated column with following dax code

Column = DATEDIFF('Table'[Date], LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Date],'Table'[Camera_id],'Table'[Camera_id],'Table'[Row Rank],'Table'[Row Rank]-1),DAY)

5. Write a measure with
   `Measure = COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE('Table', FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Column] > 21)))`
6. Create a table with following dax code

`Table 2 = SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Camera_id], ">21", [Measure]), 'Table'[Measure] >=1), "Camera_id", 'Table'[Camera_id])`

[image]

Comment: I have tried, but it seems that the the camera_id list is not correct with my requirement